# Is template parameter stacking possible in Dart?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, decorator, typedef

I'm currently trying to write a function that can take and execute any function with any set of parameters. In CPP, I do this using the following pattern;

```
template <class R, class... Args>
class Wrapper
{
private:
    R(*_function)(Args... args);

public:
    Wrapper(R(*function)(Args...)) : _function(function), _dt(dt){
      //do some init stuff here
    }

    R run(Args... args) {
        return _function(args...);
```

Is it possible to have this in dart? I can do a limited version of this in dart but I need to define a typedef with a fixed set of parameters.

```
typedef Generic<T, R> = R Function(T data);

class GenericClass<T, R>{
  Generic<T, R> callback;
  GenericClass({required this.callback});

  R method(T data){
    return callback(data);
  }
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is _variadic_ (as in "variadic generics" or "variadic templates"). [Dart/Flutter does not support them](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1014).

Comment: That's annoying. A feature like this would have allowed for much smaller code to be written. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Perhaps look into using [`Function.apply`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Function/apply.html), although using it usually is discouraged because it sacrifices compile-time type-safety.

Answer (score 0):

I got the functionality I needed based the recommendation by @jamesdlin

```
double inchestoCentimetersScaleFactor(int x, {required scale}){
  return x * 2.54 * scale;
}

T apply<T>(Function func, [List<dynamic> args = const [], Map<Symbol, dynamic> kwargs = const {}]){
  T x = Function.apply(func, args, kwargs);
  return x;
}


Future<void> main() async{
  var x = apply<double>(inchestoCentimetersScaleFactor, [3], {#scale: 4});
  print(x);
}
```

This will throw an exception if you dont provide the right arguments.